# Keycloak NodeJS adapter ignores X-Forwarded-Proto

Tags: node.js, single-sign-on, keycloak

[keycloak-connect](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect), which is the [recommended NodeJS adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_nodejs_adapter) from the Keycloak docs, does not take into account the *X-Forwarded-Proto* header when the protected application is sitting behind an Apache reverse proxy.

Indeed the redirectUri is built this way :

```
let host = request.hostname;
let headerHost = request.headers.host.split(':');
let port = headerHost[1] || '';
let protocol = request.protocol;*
let hasQuery = ~(request.originalUrl || request.url).indexOf('?');

let redirectUrl = protocol + '://' + host + (port === '' ? '' : ':' + port) + (request.originalUrl || request.url) + (hasQuery ? '&' : '?') + 'auth_callback=1';
```

`request.protocol` always is "http" due to the reverse proxy, thus the redirectUri does not have the expected protocol (HTTPS).

If this is intentional and not a bug, is using HTTP in the redirectUri a security flaw even if the client is redirect to HTTPS ? Couldn't the token have been exposed in the meantime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out to be a configuration issue on the **protected application side**, which also concern other Keycloak adapters such as the [Java Servlet Filter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_servlet_filter_adapter) adapter or the [Spring adapter](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_spring_security_adapter).

By default, any protected application will ignore the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header.

### NodeJS

The web framework used (such as Express) needs to be configured to take proxy headers into account.

For Express, [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/behind-proxies.html) states that the application should trust the proxy, e.g. :

```
app.set('trust proxy', 'loopback');
```

### Java Adapters

For Spring, there is very little configuration to do as [per the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-enable-https), in **application.properties** :

```
server.tomcat.remote-ip-header=x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol-header=x-forwarded-proto
```

For the Java Servlet Filter, there are several solutions :

A Tomcat valve can be added to **server.xml** :

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" 
           internalProxies="127.0.0.1" 
           remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" 
           proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" 
           protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" />
```

It is also possible to implement a new Servlet Filter **before** Keycloak's Filter Adapter, registered in **web.xml**, just like in [this example](https://github.com/xebia-france/xebia-servlet-extras/blob/master/src/main/java/fr/xebia/servlet/filter/XForwardedFilter.java).

Comment: This was exactly what I needed for a nodejs app with some minor modifications as detailed in the documentation you linked. Basically, since my app was deploying in a kubernetes cluster, I could not use loopback (since the reverse proxy was another node in the cluster). Instead, I had to use uniquelocal, since that includes 10.0.0.0/8, which covers all the IP addresses of the pods in my cluster.